# asp.net mvc 4 c# stop loop when form is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an application that loops over a collection and adds this to a database like this:

```
foreach( var item in collection )
{
   dal.addToDB( item );
}
```

The worrying part is that if the user closes the current page the loop continues long after.

Is there to stop the loop after the form has closed?

### Scenario

- User is adding 10,000 items to a database
- Loop begins adding the items
- An error occurs on the server or a user simply closes the page
- The loop continues

Comment: Why would it stop? You've told it to iterate over each item in the collection.

Comment: @CAbbott Can you explain how I could do that?

Comment: For asynch? You could fire off an asynch call to a controller action that adds the rows and then have a separate controller action that you poll to check to see if it's done.

Comment: I think kendo wants IIS, host, or asp.net to fire off some event that will notify his server side code to stop.

Comment: @KMC Yes that's exactly it

Comment: I have a need for this too but I need a more generic solution that applies to asp.net 4 (IIS) and 5 (dnx, .net core).

Comment: @KMC - trying to get IIS or the asp.net process to figure out if a user has closed a page, navigated away, closed their browser? I have no idea